# What is the proper way to pass a JS object as a django field value?

Tags: python, json, django

Given the following form:

```
from django import forms


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.CharField()
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from myapp.forms import MyForm


def index(request):
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This would be one possible way to do it. I'm not sure how safe or proper this is:

```
document.querySelector('#id_my_field').value = JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2})
```

and then parse the resulting string:

```
>>> json.loads(form.cleaned_data['my_field'])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Yeah, I know I could just create `a` and `b` fields and make them numeric or whatever the dtype is but this is not an option in my case because these field values will be set dynamically and how many values are expected cannot be determined in advance, so this is the convenient way to pass as many values as needed.